# What's the issue in this MATLAB Prewitt operator implementation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm trying to code an implementaiton of the Prewitt operator for edge detection. So far I've tried:

```
openImage = im2double(rgb2gray(imread(imageSource)));
[rows,cols] =  size(openImage);

N(1:rows,1:cols)=0;
for i=1:rows-2;
    for j=1:rows-2;
        N(i,j)=-1*openImage(i,j)-1*openImage(i,j+1)-1*openImage(i,j+2)+0+0+0+1*openImage(i+2,j)+1*openImage(i+2,j+1)+1*openImage(i+2,j+2);
    end;
end;
O(1:rows,1:cols)=0;
for i=1:rows-2;
    for j=1:rows-2;
        O(i,j)=-1*openImage(i,j)+0+1*openImage(i,j+2)-1*openImage(i+2,j)+0+1*openImage(i+1,j+2)-1*openImage(i+2,j)+0+1*openImage(i+2,j+2);
    end
end
Z = N + O;
```

For which I can obtain:

[image]

As it can be seen, that image got half of the image processed and half blank. What am I doing wrong?

This is original image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
I = im2double(rgb2gray(..));
[rows,cols] =  size(I);

N = zeros(size(I));
for i=2:rows-1;
    for j=2:cols-1;
        N(i,j) = 1*I(i-1,j-1) +  1*I(i-1,j) +  1*I(i-1,j+1) + ...
                 0            +  0          +  0            + ...
                -1*I(i+1,j-1) + -1*I(i+1,j) + -1*I(i+1,j+1);
    end
end

O = zeros(size(I));
for i=2:rows-1;
    for j=2:cols-1;
        O(i,j) = 1*I(i-1,j-1) + 0 + -1*I(i-1,j+1) + ...
                 1*I(i,j-1)   + 0 + -1*I(i,j+1)   + ...
                 1*I(i+1,j-1) + 0 + -1*I(i+1,j+1);
    end
end

Z = sqrt(N.^2 + O.^2);
imshow(Z)
```

Then [compare it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator#Formulation) to:

```
Gx = conv2(I, [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1]);
Gy = conv2(I, [-1 -1 -1; 0 0 0; 1 1 1]);

G = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);
T = atan2(Gy, Gx);

imshow(G)
```

Note, you might have to use `imshow(result,[])` to correctly display results outside the [0,1] range of values.

Answer (score 3):

```
for j=1:rows-2;
```

must be

```
for j=1:cols-2;
```

Comment: I get a complete white image by that

Comment: @diegoaguilar it works for me. did you change both `j`?